# Need to join attributes from one point feature class to another based on line connectivity

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, fields-attributes, spatial-join

I need points representing houses to have the ID number of the electrical pole sourcing the house.

I would use a spatial join "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", but some houses have sources that are actually closer in proximity but not connected by a line.

I must also account for houses that are connected to power sources by lines made up of multiple polyline features (I think I could handle this with a merge if necessary)

Is there a way to perform a join that joins points from two separate point feature class based on their connectivity via a third line feature class?

[image]

The homes need the attributes of the green power source that is connected to them by blue line.

Comment: No red points on a picture.

Comment: @FelixIP I see 9 red (maroon) points in the picture but I think it would help for them to be made more obvious. I also see Python and ArcPy tags but no code attempt so I’m removing them.

Comment: Are you trying to do this using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: I replaced the a picture with one with more obvious symbology. I am using ArcMap 10.6, basic license

Comment: Just in case I’ll clarify that the “power source” label at bottom of the image is referring to the green point at the intersection of the red and black lines. It is the closest power source upstream from the red point labeled “target point”

Comment: If this one off, do it manually, though with networkx module in Python it's real easy to do them all in one go.

Comment: If this is a geometric network with weights it's doable via model builder I think.

Comment: Are the blue triangles ment to be lines connecting the red points (houses) to the black lines (network), it's not clear? So all points sources/houses are points that actually intersect the network? I agree with @FelixIP this is a network solution problem rather than a spatial join because of all the exceptions you have mentioned.

Comment: The blue lines are a separate feature class of secondary lines connecting to houses. They have directional arrows, appearing like the blue line going to the target point at the top of the image when zoomed closer. A geometric network sounds like it might be the ticket

Comment: I found out that one of my most complicated exceptions was actually a mistake in the data and does not need to be accounted for. The edited post reflects this. My question is actually much more simple than I was making it- although I'm still not sure how to handle it

Comment: Can you add a screenshot

Comment: Edited to add screenshot